# How to store values from .h files?

Tags: c#

I need to read a `.h` file and store all the values. For example, `.h` files contain lines like so:

```
#define mbbh  5

#define gbnn             90

#define mkoll
```

I wrote some code to read this `.h` file (where I use string array, search for `#define` and get the value of the name i.e., `( mbbh, gbnn)- arrayname [1]`).

The problem I have is,

1. If any of these lines doesn't have the value `arrayname[2]` it throws an exception.

   `#define vkol`
2. How would I get the value of `#define` when it is not in position `arrayname[2]`?

   `#define gbbn       90`

This define statement has a value, but how can I get it?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: string[] lineParts = string.Split(line, ' ');
  if (lineParts[0] == "#define")
  {
   name = lineparts[1]
  }
  if (lineparts[2] == " ")
{
console.writeline("this const doesnt hav value");
} else { value = lineparts[2])}

Comment: It's best to show your code in the question and not in a comment. As you can most likely see it is very hard to read code in comments. Check this link for more tips : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
string[] lineParts = string.Split(line, ' ');
```

To

```
string[] lineParts = string.Split(line, ' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```